# Create a new process and make it use more than 10% CPU?

Tags: unix, cpu, process

Really odd question I know. It's to help demonstrate my university coursework. I'm going to be killing processes that are using more than 10% of the CPU.

Comment: Do you want 100% of a single logical core, or the entire CPU? [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/download/index.php) and other typical CPU benchmarking/stresstesting programs tend to be useful for these purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following super-simple C program some time ago to test scheduling algorithms, should work for you as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
  while(1==1)
    {
      int a = 400;
      a * 400;
    }
}
```

Compile with `gcc -o executable_name c_source_file.c` and run with `./executable_name`. This should give you a single process with 100% cpu usage.

Comment: Note: this would be a single thread, therefore at most it can use 100% of a single logical core. Some tools will report this as 100% per core, others report it as 100% overall (so 12.5% for a single core, if you had 8 logical cores).

Comment: @Bob, true. I also wrote a multithreaded version, but it'll only work on Solaris: http://pastebin.com/enJfLR2L